# Laravel 6.2 API, DELETE and PUT not working

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-6

**Edit: Solved: the problem was the trailing slash on the urls**

I cannot use the destroy() and update() methods of my API, it executes only the show() method.

routes:list shows all routes correctly and the controller has all required methods.

Authentication works correctly over Bearer Token.

## api.php:

```
Route::apiResource('subscriptions', 'Api\SubscriptionController')->middleware('auth:api');
```

## called urls:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1/api/subscriptions/2/
DELETE http://127.0.0.1/api/subscriptions/2/?_method=delete
```

Same with PUT and POST instead of DELETE, always executes the show() method.

store() and index() methods are working.

## Used Versions:

- Laravel 6.2
- Php 7.2.23
- Postman 7.13 (for requests)

Comment: can you remove the trailing `/` from the URLs and try again, just to see if anything odd is going on

Comment: Ok, thanks, I did not think it could be because of that, works now *facepalm*

Comment: Is it not working on postman? what are the method types and how you are passing your request parameters of PUT?